# How can I have a trigger on the same table in multiple databases without modifying the DBs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a server with dozens of "child" databases that all have the same schema/structure.  I also have a controller DB which is totally different.  What I need to do, without creating triggers in each of the child databases, is to have a trigger on the same table in each child DB... like maybe have it reside in the controller DB?  Is something like this possible?  And if so, how?

Comment: Not possible... how could you trigger off a change in a database without having a trigger in the database?

Comment: If you need a trigger, it needs to go on said tables. This honestly, however, sounds like you have a design flaw if this is the set up you have. What ever is the aim of the trigger? Is it actually logic that should actually be in the procedures you're using to interact with said tables?

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to do, without creating triggers in each of the child databases, is to have a trigger on the same table in each child DB... like maybe have it reside in the controller DB? Is something like this possible?

No. A trigger is tightly coupled to the object it references, and therefore has to live inside the same schema, inside the same database.

- Perhaps you can have a central queue table in the controller DB, the triggers just insert their relevant data into that central table, and a background process comes around and applies whatever the trigger was supposed to do to the relevant database. This at least minimizes the business logic inside the triggers.
- If a central queue table doesn't make sense, then you should be able to mitigate most of the concern through automation / deployment. I once managed 100s of databases with identical schema / procedures / triggers, and deploying a change to all of them was not really any harder than deploying a single change to one of them.